# Convert MS Word to PDF and later embed it in an HTML Page

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word, converters, embed

I currently run a Linux server, but would switch to Windows if needed.

Users will upload documents in .DOC, .DOCX or .PDF format. I want to convert the MS Word docs to PDF. Then, later, when a user loads a page which I am coding with AngularJs, the page should fetch the document from my server and embed it.

I don't want to rely on 3rd party web services, such as Google, as these are liable to change, but don't mind a 3rd party PHP library for the conversion, or maybe a "print to PDF" option, but I don't have MS Word on my server (I suppose that I could do so if I switch to windows (or use Open Office on Linux?)). Preferably free, certainly sub $100.

If fetching the doc via AJAX to the AngularJs page is problematic, I suppose that I could generate the page with the embedded PDF in PHP on the server.

I don't even know how best to go about it. Google is not my friend, the only solutions I can see for my case recommend the Google DOCs API, which is now deprecated.

I hope to here from someone who has already implemented this.

Comment: Microsoft Word documents are also liable to change. So your argument about 3rd party web services isn't all that valid. I would go for a word to pdf api services. PS: I can understand your dislike for Google. :-)

Comment: A very good point (+1).  However, there's not much that I can do about that, whereas I can control whether or not to use 3rd party services. If Word's format changes, I can manually print to PDF which seeking a solution, but if I rely  on a 3rd party which goes off-line, then I lose full functionality.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, check out a few API's, you'll see they all have a lot in common. Implement your code in such a way you can easily switch from one to another, or implement more than one API. So you even  have a backup when one goes down temporarily. Let them do the hard work for you.

Comment: That sounds reasonable (+1). Can you recommend any APIs?

Comment: No, I can Google and there are quite a few, but I have no long term experience with any of them. Sorry. I do have experience with quite a few API's and there's a lot of variety in quality and price, which you can only really discover by trying them out. I always first write my own interface, and then connect that to any API, this way you can always choose and switch.

Comment: Isn't asking for library recommendations against the questions rules? Or is when you *only* ask for a recommendation and put nothing more in the question? (don't take offense, I don't want to upset a guy that have a profile picture that suspiciously looks like a [Bond villain](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fscreencrush.com%2Ffiles%2F2014%2F12%2Flatest.png%3Fw%3D600%26h%3D0%26zc%3D1%26s%3D0%26a%3Dt%26q%3D89&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fscreencrush.com%2Fspectre-bond-and-blofeld-a-brief-history-of-007s-greatest-adversary%2F&docid=ESqQ0IAIMF8wrM&tbnid=yEZ258gOrqnZBM%3A&vet=1) :-)  )

Comment: And I will upvote you without taking offence (thanks for noticing the profile pic ;-).  If I wanted a library, I would ask on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ But I am looking for the correct approach, preferably from someone who has already done this.  I am currently leaning to using a headless LIbre Office to open  the MS Word doc & print it to PDF. Then I need to research if I can cross-domain `<embed>` the PDF doc into HTML. Any ideas?

Comment: My only suggestion is was I learned from MS bloggers, you should *not* use Office COM objects, is doable but using them from a server [is not supported by MS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). And regarding the possible off-topic, according to the flag options the problem with asking for suggestions is that "they tend to attract opinionated answers" but unfortunately for you this is not appear to be the case, hope you find a solution.